# jQuery: Radio button selection determens which div to display, with ”checked” attribute

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, click

I have a form with different options provided by radio buttons. I also have a script which displays different divs with different form inputs.

This script works fine, my problem is that I have a “previous” link where a user can go one step back and edit already entered data and that I can’t force the different options with the **checked** attribute to the radio button. It has to be clicked, which make sense because my script uses the **.click** event.

But how can I say something like: `“If $_SESSION[‘unemployed’] == ‘yes’ then echo ‘checked’”` and it shows the right option.

I hope I explained myself correctly otherwise fell free to ask.
Please see the code live here http://jsfiddle.net/GEFMX/1/ and my question is if one or more or the checkboxes default is "checked".

The Javascript I’m using looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("input[name$='step2_student']").click(function() {
        var diffoptions = $(this).val();

        $("div.studerende_janej").hide();
        $("#studerende" + diffoptions).show();
    });

    $("input[name$='step2_otheredu']").click(function() {
        var diffoptions = $(this).val();

        $("div.othereducation_janej").hide();
    $("#othereducation" + diffoptions).show();
    });

    $("input[name$='step2_haveeducation']").click(function() {
        var diffoptions = $(this).val();

        $("div.haveeducation_janej").hide();
        $("#haveeducation" + diffoptions).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Sincere
- Mestika

Comment: One thing I like to not, you can add all your handles inside one document ready function. I've edited your code block to show you how

Comment: @Anzeo you should not change that much of the OPs code. make an answer if you think it is correct.

Comment: If i understood your question correctly, you want to persist the radio button selections even after going back and forth in the browser. What you can try is saving the checked state of each radio in a cookie and process the cookie on page load.

Comment: @Neal I don't think the rewriting of the code solved anything, I encountered this question and wanted to tell him there's an easier way. I unfortunately do not have the time to take abtter look at what's wrong here

Comment: @techfoobar I guess my problem isn't to "remember" the selection of the radio button but more that if I add the attribute "chekced" to the radio button upon either a cookie or other, the Javascript won't show the divs because it is not "clicked".

@ Anzeo, thanks for your correction. I've changed my code to your edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some code to your page load to trigger a 'click' for all radios that are checked. i.e. something like:

```
$(function() {

// .. bind your click events here

$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) $(this).click(); // trigger 'click' if checked
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your document ready, add `$("input[name~='step2_']:checked").click()`.  This will trigger the click event for already checked radio buttons, effectively displaying the divs.